# C# Append at last line a character on all then one by one?

Tags: c#, text

I'm making console c# app that actually takes all lines from text1 and append to it in the end of each line a text that is ".php?" or ".html? and these texts are also lines from text2, I want to print the first one in text2 in the end of each line in text1. Then take the second one in text2 and do the same Until it finishes text2?

Here's my code:

```
string[] resultConfig = File.ReadAllLines("keywords.txt");
string[] readParameters = File.ReadAllLines("param.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < readParameters.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < resultConfig.Length ; x++)
                {
                    resultConfig[x] = resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(resultConfig[x]);
   
                }
                
            }
```

OUTPUT:
**

```
keyboards.php?.html?.asp?
karachi.php?.html?.asp?
keychain.php?.html?.asp?
in khobar.php?.html?.asp?
lebanon.php?.html?.asp?
lights.php?.html?.asp?
london.php?.html?.asp?
must have.php?.html?.asp?
```

**

**

```
WHAT IT SHOULD BE:
keyboards.php?
karachi.php?
keychain.php?
in khobar.php?
lebanon.php?
lights.php?
london.php?
must have.php?
keyboards.html?
karachi.html?
keychain.html?
in khobar.html?
lebanon.html?
lights.html?
london.html?
must have.html?
```

**
etc...

** KEYWORDS.TXT CONTAINS **

```
keyboards
karachi
keychain
in khobar
lebanon
lights
london
must have
```

** PARAM.TXT CONTAINS **

```
.php?
.asp?
.html?
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `keywords.txt` and `param.txt`?

Comment: I added it check it

Comment: You won't be able to add more items to an array than it is initialized with (it appears you want to increase the size of `resultConfig` by 3x). You may want to use a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: How can I save the results in text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line `resultConfig[x] = resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i];`. In this line you change your string in `resultConfig[x]` and since you're using a nested loop, this happens for every line in your *param.txt` file.

In order to write you desired result in the console try this code instead:

```cs
            string[] resultConfig = File.ReadAllLines("keywords.txt");
            string[] readParameters = File.ReadAllLines("param.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < readParameters.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < resultConfig.Length ; x++)
                {
                    string line = resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
   
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: How can I save the results in text file?

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding the parameter to the config and you should change the order of the loops and not change the value in the array.

Something like this:

```
string[] resultConfig = File.ReadAllLines("keywords.txt");
string[] readParameters = File.ReadAllLines("param.txt");

for (int x = 0; x < resultConfig.Length ; x++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < readParameters.Length; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: THANKS WORKED LIKE CHARRM <3 but If i want to add another thing same as readParameter? and also it will be after readParameter will I just do the same?

Comment: You can just concatenate more strings if you like `Console.WriteLine(resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i] + more);`.

Comment: How can I save the results in text file?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to save all these results in the `resultConfig` array, but you can't just add more items to an array than it was initialized with - you have to resize it first using `Array.Resize(ref resultConfig, resultConfig.Length * readParameters.Length)`.

However, even then it will be a little tricky to append to the first set of items and then add new items for the additional parameters (it can be done if that's really necessary).

Instead I would create a new `List<string>` to save the results, and leave the initial arrays as they are:

```
string[] resultConfig = 
{
    "keyboards",
    "karachi",
    "keychain",
    "in khobar",
    "lebanon",
    "lights",
    "london",
    "must have"
};

string[] readParameters = {".php?", ".html?", ".asp?"};

var allCombinations = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < readParameters.Length; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < resultConfig.Length; x++)
    {
        allCombinations.Add(resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(resultConfig[x] + readParameters[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I save the results in text file?

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(filePath, allCombinations);`